# Haskell blank space after new line

Tags: haskell

I have the following function which takes a number as a parameter and should return a string.

```
fun n = unwords [foldl (\acc x -> acc ++ (unwords[show x] ++ " ")) "" [1..nr] ++ "\n"| nr <- [n, n - 1..0]]
```

The returned value for 5 is:

```
fun 5
"1 2 3 4 5 \n 1 2 3 4 \n 1 2 3 \n 1 2 \n 1 \n \n"
```

and

```
 putStrLn $ fun 5
  1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4
 1 2 3
 1 2
 1
```

My question is where does the blank space from the start of the lines appear from? My expected result for the function is

```
fun 5
"1 2 3 4 5 \n1 2 3 4 \n1 2 3\n 1 2\n 1\n\n
```

Comment: @arrowd My output for `putStrLn $ fun 5` was the one I wrote first.

Comment: Unrelated: the innermost `unwords` is useless: `unwords [show x] = show x`.

Comment: You might want to look at `Data.List.intersperse` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The space comes from the outermost use of `unwords`, whose [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unwords) states:

> It joins words with separating spaces.

If you changed that `unwords` to `concat`, you would remove the spaces after newlines.